# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

app-component.ts

```
goRevervationPage() {
  console.log("test")
    this.navCtrl.push('ReservationPage')
}
```

app.html

```html
 <ion-list>
            <button class="sideMenuItem selectedItem" ion-item detail-none>Accueil</button>
            <button class="sideMenuItem" ion-item detail-none (click)="goRevervationPage()">Réservation</button>
            <button class="sideMenuItem" ion-item detail-none>Créer une fiche client</button>
         ..   <button class="sideMenuItem" ion-item detail-none>Fiche client</button>
            <button class="sideMenuItem" ion-item detail-none>All Clients</button>

        </ion-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to do with `NavController` in your `app.component.ts`.

But looks like you forgot to add it to the dependencies. Injecting it as a dependency in the `constructor` should make it work. Something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = TabsPage;

  constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    public navCtrl: NavController
  ) {
    ...
  }

  goRevervationPage() {
    console.log("test")
    this.navCtrl.push('ReservationPage')
  }

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give page name without quotes and u need to import the page component also in the header

```
goRevervationPage() {
  console.log("test")
  this.navCtrl.push(ReservationPage)
}
```